# Rails not receiving Ember parameters from Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data

I have a simple Ember 2.4 application. Here's the relevant code

**../models/invitation.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  email: DS.attr('string')
});
```

**../controllers/index.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({

  emailAddress: '',

  actions: {
    saveInvitation() {
      const email = this.get('emailAddress');

      const newInvitation = this.store.createRecord('invitation', {
        email: email,
      });
      newInvitation.save();
    }
  }
});
```

When I trigger the `saveInvitation` action, my Rails backend does not receive any parameters. The right action/controller receives the request but the only parameters are `{action: "create", controller: "invitations"}`.

Am I missing something? Shouldn't the parameters include the invitation with the email?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the default Ember adapter sends a content type `application/vdn.api+json` which is not automatically registered by Rails and parse the JSON arguments.

A fix for this was to register the right mime types under rails config

```
api_mime_types = %W(
  application/vnd.api+json
  text/x-json
  application/json
)

Mime::Type.unregister :json
Mime::Type.register 'application/json', :json, api_mime_types
```

See https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/1027

Answer (score 0):

add following to config/initializers/json_adapter.rb

```
ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller) do
 require 'active_model_serializers/register_jsonapi_renderer'
end
```

This may helps